# How to style "Read More" using CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my JQuery function below. I want to apply a CSS style to "Read More" and "Read Less" text, which are part of the function. How do we do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.YourName').jTruncate({ 
    length: 25, 
    minTrail: 0,
    moreText: "Read More", 
    lessText: "Read Less", 
    ellipsisText: "...", 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tester3.yolasite.com/resources/javascript/jtruncate.js"></script> 

<p class="YourName">Hello, Text will truncate after 25 characters and a "Read More" link will be appended to it. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more more text. Here is some more text. Here is some more text. This is the end.</p>
```

Comment: There's no way to style JS strings. You should apply CSS to the elements showing these strings on a page. You're using this [jTruncate](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate)?

Comment: Can you please provide an example. Or is there an alternative route to include the "Read More" in my HTML doc so that I can style it using CSS3.

Comment: Please explain to us what `jTruncate()` is, or what it is supposed to do. Also please make the snippet work: on **Run** I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". You should deliver it to us error free.

Comment: I have included the HTML and JQuery syntax. jTruncate() is a javascript library imported into my file.

Answer (score 6):

```
moreText: "<span class='moreText'>Read More</span>", // The text to use for the "more" link. 
lessText: "<span calss='readLess'>Read Less</span>", // The text to use for the "less" link.
```

and then in your css style them as usual...

```
.moreText{/* styles here */}
.readLess{/* styles here */}
```

Comment: It does not work when I include the <span>. When I click on "Read More" I get <span class='moreText'>Read More</span>

Comment: Can we style the "Read More" in the following: var moreText: "Read More",

Comment: @Vyas - you're seeing the HTML because you're using `.text()` to insert the code. use `.html()` instead. Otherwise apply the styles to the element that you're inserting to. You cannot style a text node, only it's surrounding elements.